# No detect new lines inside a file for contruct a csv file in bash

Tags: bash, csv, parsing, scripting

I am making a csv constructor but I have some problems.

I have files like this `characteristics.tmp`

```
1083108343
1083108360
1083108378
1083108386
```

I have to build to this format: `Name, "1083108343 ,1083108360 , 1083108378,1083108386"`;
I tried this

`cat characteristics.tmp| paste -s -d, -`

I also tried `tr '\n' ','`

But the output is like if there is only one element. I check the file with xxd and the character `0d0a` is as it should be in the end of every line? So why is not detecting the others?

`,1083108386`

Comment: `0d0a` makes it sound like you're on windows. `dos2unix < characteristics.tmp | tr '\n' , | sed 's/,$/\n/'` may do the trick.

Comment: This might help: `dos2unix <characteristics.tmp | paste -s -d ','`

Comment: @Cyrus Yeah, that's even nicer.

Comment: no bro i am on Ubuntu 18 :D but bro i find something interesting i pass the file to xxd characteristics.tmp and see this " 3130 3833 3130 3833 3433 0d0a 3130 " for a reason there is a " 0d0a" in the end of all lines maybe that is why the paste and tr doesn't work correct.

Answer (score 0):

Cyrus bro thank you very much. I have the solution may be useful for someone

The file have 0d0a in all end lines that is like windows works. That is why when i pass to xxd this 0d0a appears and bash works only with 0a for new line so I pass the file to dos2unix as you said and results the file is only with 0a that is the new line that is the way unix works.

BEFORE

xxd file.tmp

`00000000: 3130 3633 3234 3234 3432 **0d0a**            1063242442..`

AFTER dos2unix

`00000000: 3130 3633 3234 3234 3432 **0a**              1063242442.`

And finally all the commands like xargs,tr,paste works correct.

Thanks to everyone :D